# How to ignore 404 exceptions in Rollbar?

Tags: python, django, rollbar

I'm using Rollbar in a Django 1.11.9 app (Python 2.7) and I'm trying without success to configure it to ignore 404 exceptions.

I've checked [Rollbar docs for Python](https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/python) and noticed I'm already using the configuration `'exception_level_filters': [(Http404, 'ignored')]` which is not working at all. So first I thought the library I was using was raising a different type of exception ([Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/)) and tried to add its `NotFound` exception in the `exception_level_filters`, but (1) it didn't work and (2) the 404 exceptions were not being ignored for modules not using this library as well. So I checked my views and found out there was a custom view handling 404 errors, which simply used the Django logging method to log the request path in debug level. I've tried editing the logging settings by removing Rollbar from the logger handlers with level debug  and even removed the logging in the custom view, however I still get Rollbars for 404 errors.

I've also tried using the Rollbar configuration `ignorable_404_urls` with the value `re.compile('.*')` hoping it would ignore for all URLs, but it didn't work as well.

Has anyone been able to do it properly in a Django app and/or seen any mistake I've made? Thanks in advance!

Edit: pyrollbar version: 0.14.0

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the Django logging module was forwarding 404 errors to Rollbar with warning level. To fix it I had to add the following configurations to my logging settings (`loggers` key):

```
'django.request': {
    'handlers': ['console', 'rollbar'],
    'level': 'ERROR',
    'propagate': False,
},
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc:](https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/python#django)

> Additionally, you can use the key 'ignorable_404_urls' to set an
>   iterable of regular expression patterns to use to determine whether a
>   404 exception should be ignored based on the full url path for the
>   request. For example,

```py
import re
ROLLBAR = {
    'access_token': 'POST_SERVER_ITEM_ACCESS_TOKEN',
    'environment': 'development' if DEBUG else 'production',
    'branch': 'master',
    'root': '/absolute/path/to/code/root',
    'ignorable_404_urls': (
        re.compile('/index\.php'),
        re.compile('/foobar'),
    ),
}
```